# How do I use text as pagination with Owl Carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel, sliders

Using [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) I wanted to use text from the `alt="Image Alt Text"` or `title="Image Title Text"` of images as pagination instead of bullets / circles. In the process of writing the question and fiddles I sussed it. See below. Hope this is useful to someone else.

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uz2jfe2w/47/)

Comment: remove you comment, I added your fiddle in your question, remember to edit your question instead of putting in comment.

Answer (score 5):

To prevent the pager disappearing whenever the slider is re-sized (such as on a responsive site), add this to your owl config:

```
afterUpdate: customPager
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/peterhay/xrqjaxk7/

Note: Someone deleted this comment last time. Presumably for not answering the question. However it wasn't really a question to begin with and I think this is an important addition to the original post, which could save someone a lot of headache. I don't currently have the "50 reputation" required to comment on a question.

Answer (score 0):

The custom function works with a single item:

singleItem: true,

But if I have say 4 items then it only shows the first 2 as menu paginations.